# Execute a command in a script and kill it when pressing a key

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script which records my voice until I press a concrete key. I have thought I could use this command

```
arecord -D hw -q -f cd -r 16000 speech.wav
```

which records from my laptop microphone and stops when the process is killed, but I don't know how to write bash code to call the process and then kill it when I press a concrete key. Can you help me?

Comment: press a determined key ?

Comment: A concrete key, I meant . Sorry. A key that I will decide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
key="q"
arecord speech.wav &
pid=$!
while read -n1 char ; do
  if [ "$char" = "$key" ] ; then
    kill "$pid"
    break
  fi
done
```

$! notation is the pid of last background job. the read builtin has the -n switch, with this switch only a number of characters instead of a full line is read at once.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know the $! sintax

Comment: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/116783-bash-replacement-getchar.html this page briefly mentions about controlling the tty echo by stty(1).

Comment: Can you please indent your code more than one space?